# How to disable the tooltip in MySQL Workbench?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

MySQL Workbench is an excellent tool. But, the tooltip really irritates me because it hides objects in the diagram and does not display any useful information for me.

I could not disable the tooltip, any idea to disable it?

[I am using V 6.0 on OS X Mavericks]

[image]

Comment: Tsuperuser disable tooldtips mysql workbench

Comment: [Answered on SuperUser](http://superuser.com/questions/744179/how-do-you-hide-tool-tips-in-mysql-workbench)